# context method emitFile() is not supported in serve mode. This plugin is likely not vite-compatible

Tags: svelte, rollup, vite, sveltekit

This is in my part of  `svelte.config.js`

```
 transform() {
  const css = getAtomicCss(allPaths);

  this.emitFile({
    type: "asset",
    source: css,
    id: "",
    fileName: "main.css",
  });
},
```

this.emitFile work good with `generateBundle` in rollUp now I can't see any alternative of this.emitFile in `vite`.
What should I do?

Comment: Can you post your full svelte.config.js?